# Plot scalar and vectorial solution constant on each CELL=square in paraview/vtk

Tags: paraview, vtk

I have the velocity (vector) and pressure (scalar). This solution is constant in each CELL (square) of the mesh. I don't know why does not appear the pressure information when I open the file in paraview. I write an example of a mesh of the unit square [0,1]x[0,1] consisting on 4 squares (CELLS) of equal dimensions, and then this mesh has 9 POINTS. On each square I have a constant solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

````
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Little example
ASCII

DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 9 DOUBLE
  0.0  0.0  0.0
  0.5  0.0  0.0
  1.0  0.0  0.0
  0.0  0.5  0.0
  0.5  0.5  0.0
  1.0  0.5  0.0
  0.0  1.0  0.0
  0.5  1.0  0.0
  1.0  1.0  0.0

CELLS 4 20
  4  0  1  4  3
  4  1  2  5  4
  4  3  4  7  6
  4  4  5  8  7

CELL_TYPES 4
  9
  9
  9
  9

CELL_DATA 4
VECTORS Velocity DOUBLE
    0.00000   0.0000   0.0000
    1.00000  10.0000   0.0000
    2.00000  20.0000   0.0000
    3.00000  30.0000   0.0000
         
CELL_DATA 4
SCALARS Pressure DOUBLE
LOOKUP_TABLE default
    0.00000
    1.00000
    2.00000
    3.00000
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only one `CELL_DATA` tag in your file. Remove the second one to fix your problem.

Some (partial) doc can be found [here](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/VTKFileFormats/#legacy-file-examples)